# Check connect internet when using GET or POST in FastAndroidNetworking

Tags: android

I recently started using FastAndroidNetworking in recent time. 
I want to call again the call function to the API when my connection is interrupted, but there is no way to check the internet connection in this function:

```
public static void getListTrendSearch(final Context context, final 
NetworkListener delegateNetworkListener){
    AndroidNetworking.get(myURL)
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    delegateNetworkListener.onNetworkSuccess(response);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                }
            });
}
```

Somebody help me.
[Link to FastAndroidNetworking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for internet connection before calling the function like:

```
if(isInternetConnected()) {
  makeNetworkCall();
} else {
 displayNetworkError();
}
```

Moreover, you can apply your logic based on the error code like:

```
    @Override
      public void onError(ANError anError) {
      if(networkError()){
 displayNetworkError();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check Internet connection simply calling this function*(put this function in Global/General .java file if you create otherwise it's okay)**

```
// Function to check Internet Connectivity
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    boolean isConnected = false;
    if (context != null) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    return isConnected;
}
```

**Then call this function from your Activity or Fragment.**

```
if(AppGlobal.isNetworkAvailable(this))

{
    //put your API call here} else {
   //NOTE:-here i set no internet connection dialog you can set your on things

    AppDialog.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, null,
            getString(R.string.txt_no_network), getString(R.string.txt_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

Happy Learning......